# Doorbell hack - remote unlock door

Tags: capacitor, audio, relay, frequency, remote-control

We need to use the audio output of a wireless doorbell to trigger a stable DC voltage which is going to keep switched a 3.3V DC relay as long as the audio output is present.

The relay is supposed to power/open an electronic lock until the doorbell audio finishes.

The doorbell I'm using is also a 3.3V device.

When applying the audio output directly to the relay, the relay was playing the audio just like a loudspeaker. This happened even when I tried to even out the audio using capacitors.

*Here's an image of the Doorbell used*

[image: The Wireless doorbell I used]

*And this is the wireless switch for the same doorbell*

[image]

*These are the capacitors I tried for smoothing away the audio*

[image]

The relay was still playing the audio like a loudspeaker (instead of being switched) even after I used these capacitors. do you think capacitors with different values could help or are there better solutions?

Comment: The audio will be AC. The relay requires DC. Did you rectify the signal?

Comment: @Transistor with a diode rectifier? no, I didn't use any diodes since it seemed like only the positive wire is modulated for the audio. can a four diodes rectifier solve my problem?

Comment: I don't know. You haven't given enough details on the doorbell or on the relay. A bridge rectifier will drop 1.2 to 1.4 V which you probably can't afford on a 3.3 V circuit.

Comment: @Transistor I also have a 5-volt power source; I could use the 3.3V source to drive the 5V source and power the relay using that.

Comment: @Transistor I can change the relay with whatever relay you think can do the job. about the doorbell, the loudspeaker of the doorbell was a 5 ohm one. let me know if there's a specific parameter you need in your calculations. thanks

Comment: Is the relay a plain relay or one of the relay modules on a PCB with an option isolator. Part number? Link to datasheet?

Comment: @Transistor it's a plain one and I can't get my hands on a relay module here in Afghanistan if you mean a relay module instead of a plain relay would solve the issue.

Comment: Post a photo of the doorbell PCB and relay. What else have you got available? NPN / PNP transistors, diodes, capacitors?

Comment: @Transistor I tried a few things on my own and ended up burning the entire thing up. I still have the doorbells though. I'll post images of that.

Comment: @Transistor I've added some photos.

Comment: @S.Goody Thanks for some details and your responses here. It's likely that the audio signal isn't even 3.3 V. Do you intend on keeping the audio, but want to detect it as well for enabling the relay, too? In other words, are you willing to remove the speaker? Or so you want to keep it and just add a relay circuit? (I do understand that you have available both 3.3 VDC and 5 VDC power supply rails.)

Answer (score 1):

If the relay isn't switching, you will likely need to buffer the audio output with a transistor. Just because the audio output is 3.3V doesn't mean that it can supply enough current to switch the relay. If you feed the audio signal into a transistor that switches the relay, and then put your capacitor from the base of the transistor to ground, you should be able to make the relay switch.